# unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml": no matches for

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, flanneld

need help.

I must to install Exchange Listener with instruction https://community.terrasoft.ru/articles/1-realnyy-primer-po-razvertyvaniyu-servisa-exchange-listener-s-ispolzovaniem-kubernetes
Some month ago I do it, but now i see the mistake

adminka@l-test:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"

What need to do?

> adminka@l-test:~$ kubectl -n kube-system get pods  --all-namespaces
> NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS
> RESTARTS   AGE kube-system   coredns-78fcd69978-mrb58         1/1
> Running   0          2d12h kube-system   coredns-78fcd69978-pwp2n
> 1/1     Running   0          2d12h kube-system   etcd-l-test
> 1/1     Running   0          2d12h kube-system   kube-apiserver-l-test
> 1/1     Running   0          2d12h kube-system
> kube-controller-manager-l-test   1/1     Running   0          2d12h
> kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-kx9sm            1/1     Running   0
> 2d12h kube-system   kube-proxy-v2f9q                 1/1     Running
> 0          2d12h kube-system   kube-scheduler-l-test            1/1
> Running   0          2d12h

```
> adminka@l-test:~$ kubectl describe pod kube-flannel-ds-kx9sm -n
> kube-system Name:                 kube-flannel-ds-kx9sm Namespace:    
> kube-system Priority:             2000001000 Priority Class Name: 
> system-node-critical Node:                 l-test/192.168.0.71 Start
> Time:           Sat, 18 Sep 2021 00:36:50 +0300 Labels:              
> app=flannel
>                       controller-revision-hash=7fb8b954f9
>                       pod-template-generation=1
>                       tier=node Annotations:          <none> Status:               Running IP:                   192.168.0.71 IPs:   IP:          
> 192.168.0.71 Controlled By:  DaemonSet/kube-flannel-ds Init Containers:   install-cni:
>     Container ID:  docker://01da25d6de8d2b679c9035d25fcd10de432388875fd90b23756c6e1b8392af21
>     Image:         quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.14.0
>     Image ID:      docker-pullable://quay.io/coreos/flannel@sha256:4a330b2f2e74046e493b2edc30d61fdebbdddaaedcb32d62736f25be8d3c64d5
>     Port:          <none>
>     Host Port:     <none>
>     Command:
>       cp
>     Args:
>       -f
>       /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json
>       /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist
>     State:          Terminated
>       Reason:       Completed
>       Exit Code:    0
>       Started:      Sat, 18 Sep 2021 00:36:56 +0300
>       Finished:     Sat, 18 Sep 2021 00:36:56 +0300
>     Ready:          True
>     Restart Count:  0
>     Environment:    <none>
>     Mounts:
>       /etc/cni/net.d from cni (rw)
>       /etc/kube-flannel/ from flannel-cfg (rw)
>       /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-28x6l (ro) Containers:   kube-flannel:
>     Container ID:  docker://b109519d917ceb9d05c19421e5e65ece948977ce6b98d1e638f005250ddc9814
>     Image:         quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.14.0
>     Image ID:      docker-pullable://quay.io/coreos/flannel@sha256:4a330b2f2e74046e493b2edc30d61fdebbdddaaedcb32d62736f25be8d3c64d5
>     Port:          <none>
>     Host Port:     <none>
>     Command:
>       /opt/bin/flanneld
>     Args:
>       --ip-masq
>       --kube-subnet-mgr
>     State:          Running
>       Started:      Sat, 18 Sep 2021 00:36:57 +0300
>     Ready:          True
>     Restart Count:  0
>     Limits:
>       cpu:     100m
>       memory:  50Mi
>     Requests:
>       cpu:     100m
>       memory:  50Mi
>     Environment:
>       POD_NAME:       kube-flannel-ds-kx9sm (v1:metadata.name)
>       POD_NAMESPACE:  kube-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
>     Mounts:
>       /etc/kube-flannel/ from flannel-cfg (rw)
>       /run/flannel from run (rw)
>       /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-28x6l (ro) Conditions:   Type              Status  
> Initialized       True   Ready             True   ContainersReady  
> True   PodScheduled      True Volumes:   run:
>     Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
>     Path:          /run/flannel
>     HostPathType:   cni:
>     Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
>     Path:          /etc/cni/net.d
>     HostPathType:   flannel-cfg:
>     Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
>     Name:      kube-flannel-cfg
>     Optional:  false   kube-api-access-28x6l:
>     Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
>     TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
>     ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
>     ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
>     DownwardAPI:             true QoS Class:                   Burstable Node-Selectors:              <none> Tolerations:            
> :NoSchedule op=Exists
>                              node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
>                              node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
>                              node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule op=Exists
>                              node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
>                              node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
>                              node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
>                              node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists Events:         
> <none> adminka@l-test:~$
```

Comment: Please can you post the result of a `kubectl version` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

v1beta1 is not compatible with your cluster version. Use v1 instead.